# After updating to Flutter 3.10 : screen not scrolling up when keyboard appears / ResizeToAvoidBottomInset stopped working

Tags: android, flutter, dart, uiscrollview, flutter-3.10

I have updated flutter sdk to latest 3.10.0 and dart 3 then  screen not scrolling up when keyboard appears in android, mostly when a text field get focus. Before this update it was working fine in flutter sdk version 3.7 etc..

Tried using
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false / true
SingleSchildScrollView -reverse - true etc

Answer (score 7):

Update :- latest version of ScreenUtil (5.8.2) they changed **useInheritedMediaQuery** default value to true

---

As per the discussion in [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126585) I have fixed this issue in my app.

This issue can be fixed by
Upgrading ScreenUtil to latest (5.8.1) and setting

`useInheritedMediaQuery = true`

```
flutter_screenutil: ^5.8.1

ScreenUtilInit(
  useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
  designSize: const Size(376, 812),
  builder: (context, child) {
    return const Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Spacer(),
          TextField(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  },
);
```